# How to draw a CollisionObject from fcl library in Rviz?

Tags: ros, fcl, collision-object, librviz, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a collision object from FCL library as follows:

```
        boost::shared_ptr<Sphere> Shpere0(new Sphere(0.5));
        Transform3f tf0 ; 
         tf0.setIdentity();
         tf0.setTranslation(Vec3f(0,0,0));
         tf0.setQuatRotation(Quaternion3f(0, 0, 0, 0));
         CollisionObject co0(Shpere0, tf0);
```

// I want to draw the Collision Object in Rviz..

Any suggestions ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203415/how-to-draw-a-collisionobject-from-fcl-library-in-rviz?/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be interested in the [moveit_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_visual_tools) by Dave Coleman.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1